# Searchbox with Reactive Extensions and textbox Textchanged event

Tags: winforms, system.reactive, observable, search-box

I'm having troubles building a searchbox with reactive extensions.
My goal is to get the latest text available every X milliseconds, do my search and post results back on a UI grid (winforms). But i'm stuck with first step.

I can see by logging that multiple events are fired in 5000 milliseconds using Rx Sample, not only one! I expected 1 time every 5000 ms max.

My code is really simple and i strongly believed it worked:

```
        EventLoopScheduler scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler(ts => new Thread(ts));   
        Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(this.textBox1, "TextChanged")
        .Sample(new TimeSpan(5000), scheduler).ObserveOn(this).Subscribe
        (
            args =>
            {
                string text = ((TextBox)args.Sender).Text;
                Console.WriteLine("Sample fired. Text: {0}", text);
            }
        );
```

I'm wiring up everything in the constructor of a Form.
Am i messing up with scheduler?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try removing the `scheduler` argument and the `.ObserveOn(this)` operator?

Comment: Cannot remove them, need responsive UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `new TimeSpan(5000)` which is 5000 ticks and not very long at all, use `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)`.